# Yet Another Maven 'Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration' Error

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

This POM.XML produces the following error on line 55:

`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.peterlavalle:sablecc-maven-plugin:3.7:generate (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.conserveestate</groupId>
    <artifactId>EstateAccountingInExLoader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EstateAccountingInExLoader</name>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.peterlavalle</groupId>
                <artifactId>sablecc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/gen-java</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.peterlavalle</groupId>
                <artifactId>sablecc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/gen-java</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>  <!-- Line 55: Error - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error seems to indicate that the plug in is expecting a `generate-sources` goal instead of `generate`.  If I change the goal to `generate-sources`, Eclipse removes the red X in the XML file and no errors are displayed, but... When I build the project, I get this error:

`Could not find goal 'generate-sources' in plugin com.peterlavalle:sablecc-maven-plugin:3.7 among available goals generate`

So this looks like a contradiction to me.  I specify a goal of `generate` I get a message saying the plugin expects `generate-sources` but if I change the goal to `generate-sources` then I get a message which seems to indicate the plugin is expecting a goal of `generate`.

The plugin invokes SableCC (a compiler compiler) which reads a grammar file and generates Java source code that gets compiled along with my code that invokes the generated parser.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

As per  khmarbaise's suggestion, I tried this from the command line.  Here are those results with a goal of `generate-sources`:

```
C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.conserveestate:EstateAccountingInExLoader:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 38, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< com.conserveestate:EstateAccountingInExLoader >------------
[INFO] Building EstateAccountingInExLoader 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.364 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T09:33:28-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'generate-sources' in plugin com.peterlavalle:sablecc-maven-plugin:3.7 among available goals generate -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException

C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader>
```

And again with a goal of `generate`.  This time it works.

```
C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.conserveestate:EstateAccountingInExLoader:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 38, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< com.conserveestate:EstateAccountingInExLoader >------------
[INFO] Building EstateAccountingInExLoader 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sablecc-maven-plugin:3.7:generate (default) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---

 -- Generating parser for Scraper.grammar in C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader\src\main\gen-java
Adding productions and alternative of section AST.
Verifying identifiers.
Verifying ast identifiers.
Adding empty productions and empty alternative transformation if necessary.
Adding productions and alternative transformation if necessary.
computing alternative symbol table identifiers.
Verifying production transform identifiers.
Verifying ast alternatives transform identifiers.
Generating token classes.
Generating production classes.
Generating alternative classes.
Generating analysis classes.
Generating utility classes.
Generating the lexer.
 State: INITIAL
 - Constructing NFA.
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
 - Constructing DFA.
.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................................................................................
 - resolving ACCEPT states.
Generating the parser.
.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................
..
.......................................................................................
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 65 source files to C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader\target\EstateAccountingInExLoader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ EstateAccountingInExLoader ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader\target\EstateAccountingInExLoader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\mbmas_000\.m2\repository\com\conserveestate\EstateAccountingInExLoader\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\EstateAccountingInExLoader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader\pom.xml to C:\Users\mbmas_000\.m2\repository\com\conserveestate\EstateAccountingInExLoader\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\EstateAccountingInExLoader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.091 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T09:30:32-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EstateAccountingInExLoader>
```

Comment: This WARNING is usually given by M2Eclipse where the M2E Eclipse plugin does not know anything about that plugin. The most important question is: Does this build work fine on plain command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise See my update.

Comment: Please add those outputs as text in the post and not as images...cause some of use are not allowed to access those images...

Comment: @khmarbaise Done.

Comment: First the error message shows that the posted pom files does not represent the used pom file cause: `Could not find goal 'generate-sources' in plugin com.peterlavalle:sablecc-maven-plugin:3.7 among available goals generate` shows an other goal is used?